# Tcl search /and remove

Tags: string, tcl

I have a hierarchy string

```
Aa/bb/cc/dd
Ff/gg/hh/ii
```

I can get length but don't know how to get the index of last "/"
How to get the output one hierarchy above?

```
Aa/bb/cc
Ff/gg/hh
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the last component like that, use one of:

1. `regsub {/[^/]+$} $input ""` — *not* for filenames!
2. `join [lrange [split $input "/"] 0 end-1] "/"` — *not* for filenames!
3. `file dirname $input` — for filenames

That has to be lifted to work over a list of values. The `lmap` command is convenient for that; for example:

```
set outputList [lmap value $inputList {file dirname $value}]
```